# How to make a default configuration for boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to create a tool for our helpdesk team to have a minimal interface to restart our production servers in AWS. I'm using the AWS boto3 module and I'm using multiple regions, do I need to write a config file?

How do I tell boto3 where is the config file?

What I tried so far only succeed when I'm telling boto3 to use one region but we are using a few regions in our servers.

What I tried so far was:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=("eu-west-1a","eu-west-1c"))
```

and it didn't succeed. What I should do?

Comment: region_name=("eu-west-1a","eu-west-1c")** sory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169112/launching-ec2-in-multiple-regions-using-boto3. Authentication needed by boto3 can be handled by using profiles or by using env variables and exporting them

Comment: You can't specify multiple regions into one variable, you should use a separate variable for second region. `ec2_region1 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="eu-west-1a")` and `ec2_region2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="eu-west-1c")`

Answer (score 2):

It is important to separate the concept of `region` which is something like `eu-west-1, us-gov-east-1` and availability zones likes `eu-west-1a`. The regions indicate a general location, like a country or a state. Within each region there are generally 3 availability zones, which are specified with letters, and indicate geographical different locations. This allows you to guarantee higher availability. Read more on the internet like [here](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-regions-and-availability-zones-the-simplest-explanation-you-will-ever-find-around/).

**Regions in python**

You can fix this on the python side using the suggestion of @Orest Gulman:

```
ec2_euwest = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="eu-west-1") 
ec2_usgoveast1 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-gov-east-1")
```

**Regions by configuration**

But you can also solve it in `user\.aws\credentials` by specifying

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<yourkeyid>
aws_secret_access_key=<yoursecretkey>

[euwest] 
role_arn=<ifwanted>
source_profile=default 
region=eu-west-1

[usgov]
role_arn=<ifwanted>
source_profile=default 
region=us-gov-east-1
```

And then connect using different sessions

```
 session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='euwest')
 ec2_euwest1 = session.resource('ec2')
```

**Availabilty zones in python**

To create an ec2 instance in a specified availability zone, you do this at startup time.

```
 session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='euwest')
 ec2_euwest = session.resource('ec2')
 ec2_euwest.create_instances(
     ImageId='ami-00b6a8a2bd28daf19',
     MinCount=1,
     MaxCount=2,
     InstanceType='t2.micro',
     KeyName='ec2-keypair'
     Placement={
        'AvailabilityZone': 'eu-west-1c',
     }
 )
```

Comment: eu-west-1a is not a valid region, eu-west-1 is. Similarly you need only 1 configuration section per account and iterate over the list of regions in the code.